# How to use jqueryUI droppable in Google App Script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-apps-script

I have the following very simple code using jquery UI. It works perfectly fine on local browser, but if I use it on google App script it doesnt work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="droppable">Drop here</div>
<div id="draggable">Drag me</div>

<script>
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped" );
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: And there's 0 console errors?

Comment: the apps script code would be helpful as well

Answer (score 2):

Use the example source from http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ as a model (dropping the head and body tags) you will find it works with htmlservice as expected. Don't forget the .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);